# ever-increasing INSERT times into a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, insert

I have 30 tables of data that I'm running a query on, and then inserting the query results into a single main table.  The query on each of the 30 tables will return 2-3 million rows, so the table itself should have about 60 million rows by the end of the query.

I'm doing each query separately, one at a time in a batch script, and with each in its own transaction, and committing it after the insert, so there should be no issue of a transaction log.

I'm finding that as more data is inserted into the table, the insert times are increasing, from roughly 5 mins for the first few tables to over 2 hrs for the 20th table.  I'm trying to figure out why this is.

My query is essentially:

```
insert into maintable <columns>
select <columns> from table1
```

The query is a bit more complex than that, but I don't believe the query is the issue.  I've tested the queries, and they return within a couple of minutes if I don't do the insert, so that shouldn't be the issue.  I've also tested inserting the results into a temptable, which takes only a few mins, and then inserting into the maintable using a select on the temptable, which again takes hours.

On the main table that I'm inserting into, I've removed the clustered index, so it only has a single index on it, so that shouldn't be an issue.

Would anyone have any tips on what I need to look for in order to diagnose what the problem is?

The one thing is that this is located on a VMWare VM, and the databases are located on the same datastore.  Could this be an issue?

UPDATE:

The create statement for the main table is the following:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[dow30_1s](
[id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[symbol] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
[transactionTime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[openPrice] [decimal](20, 8) NOT NULL,
[highPrice] [decimal](20, 8) NOT NULL,
[lowPrice] [decimal](20, 8) NOT NULL,
[closePrice] [decimal](20, 8) NOT NULL,
[vol] [int] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [dow30_1s_tt] ON [dbo].[dow30_1s] 
(
[transactionTime] ASC
)
INCLUDE ( [closePrice],
[vol]) WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, 
IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON,     
ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: Sounds like a statistics-related problem...maybe

Comment: do you have a unique key or primary key on the table, something that sql server must check against before inserting a record, perhaps the statistics are off...run this `update statistics <table_name>` and then see if your insert time improves - just a an idea

Comment: Have you looked at the execution plan at all?

Comment: Thanks for the responses.  The table that I'm inserting into does not have a primary key or a unique key, so I don't think that it's a statistics issue.  I do have a single index on there, but it's not unique, so I don't think this is the issue.

I did look at the execution plan for both the inserts and the query itself, but there wasn't anything particularly interesting.  I will try to get an execution plan to see if I can see anything of interest.

Comment: It would be worth checking out the estimated rows in the execution plan just to see...

Comment: post your CREATE TABLE sql with indexes and all for the table you are inserting into - i'm wandering if your remaining index is on a date field

Comment: Actually, the index is on a date field.  Is this an issue?

Comment: I had a problem before related to a hot-spot created by inserting ascending dates into a very large table as described by this link: http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2011/03/22/statistics-row-estimations-and-the-ascending-date-column/

Comment: I would try either removing all remaining indexes(target table of course) or updating statistics - Then try inserting a batch

Comment: drop the index and add it later, let me know if that helps

Comment: wow I can tell you right now that I restarted my runs after dropping the index, and the next batch ran taking just 6 mins!  And the activity on my server had jumped from almost nil to > 50%, which is good because it means it's doing work.  Thanks so much!!!  I just need to understand why updating statistics are important for inserts, but I guess that's a question for another thread.  How do I mark your answer as the solution?

Comment: @steve8918 - What recovery model is your database in? What are the auto grow settings on your data and log files? Are you using the `TABLOCK` hint to take advantage of minimal logging?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drop the index on `transactionTime`. <s>Smells like statistics are not being updated (running slower as the table grows larger)... Not sure if that is the culprit or just that your data is widely dispersed and maintaing the index each time you insert 2-3 million more rows is bogging sql server down.</s> The good news is you don't need that index until you are done inserting all the records, so just drop it.

Comment: Yes, as indicated in the comments above, this was the source of my problems.  After I dropped the index, my inserts went from hours to about 6 mins, which is perfectly reasonable, given my hardware.  Could this be related to index thrashing or something like that, or is it just a matter of the statistics being out of date?  I'm trying to understand how this would affect my inserts, since the index itself is just a regular index that isn't forcing uniqueness, so I don't know why the index itself would need to be accessed during an insert.

Comment: @stev8918- can't say for sure which one it was without really being able to check out the query plan and io stats, etc. It could very well be 'index thrashing', I usually remove all indexes when possible on large inserts because they do burden performance a good bit.

Comment: statistics are irrelevant to the performance of insert operations.

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend doing these inserts in a larger batch rather than one row at a time. I can't really show you a query to do that, because you didn't provide any details about your tables.

VMWare is not the problem.

Not having a clustered index could be an issue. While sometimes inserting into a heap can be faster, you should be aiming to insert the data in the same order as the clustered index.

You might also consider creating a view (or multiple views) instead of constantly moving all that data around.

Comment: doesn't sound like he is inserting one record at a time, from what I gather he is inserting 30 batches of 2-3 million records, one batch at a time

Comment: To get more specific about my tables, they're 30 tables containing every stock transaction for the Dow 30 components for 2011.  I didn't want to describe them in the question because I didn't want to put too much info in there.  Basically, each stock is its own table.  I do a single query on each table, doing a group-by on a per-second basis so that I get the Opening price, high, low and closing price  and total volume for each second, and then dump it into my main table, so that I can do queries across all the dow components.